# Energy consumption Calculation

Tags: amperage, energy, watts, power-consumption, volts

I work for a food processing plant and working on a project that calculates energy consumption.  Am having a hard time converting information given by the manufacture to calculate the average kWh.  Here are some examples of the information given.  Can anyone help figure out the consumption, or explain how I can go about figuring it out please?

We have a machine that is 230V 30Amps, it averages 12 Amps during operation if we run for one hr what would be the kWh for that hr?

Another machine at 480 Watts 3 phase that runs 16Amps on average what would by that kWh?

One more question, if I have the Max kVA a machine max load is how can I figure out the max kWh for that machine?

Thank you, hope I can get feedback.

Answer (score 1):

**At unity power factor:**

- Single phase power = Iaverage X Voltage
- Three phase power = Iaverage X Voltage X sqrt(3).

**With non unity power factor:**

Above figures are kVA
Power = kVA X Power_factor